# How do I get rid of the pixelation that occurs when I render on Cycles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

The pixelation gets worse if I rotate my view around the object in question.

I've tried increasing the viewport frames, changing the resolution, and playing around with the quality.

[image]

Comment: Hi. In future please use the built-in uploader when adding images. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post . Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This generally happens when you have SSS on.

Try adding a denoiser node and rendering it:

[image]

End result:

[image]

Viewport:

[image]

Hope this helps!